# URI path not absolute exception java(not android)

Tags: java, file, exception, path, uri

I have the following piece of source code

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

    File file = new File("pic.png");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    String string = "pic.png";
 //the code works fine until here
    URI path = new URI(string);
    File f = new File(path);
    ColorProcessor image = new ColorProcessor(ImageIO.read(f));
```

So the path that the File gets is correct. Image is buffered correctly also.
Now my problem is that i'm getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Why is my path not absolute?And how do i do it right?

If i change the path like this:

```
String string = "C:'\'Users'\'Jurgen'\'newFile'\'myProject'\'pic.png";
```

Also tried like this

```
String string = "C:/Users/Jurgen/newFile/myProject/pic.png";
```

Then i get a new exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

P.S. not working with android packages for uri

Thanks in advance=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to create uniform resource identifier, but the name should follow the [url conventions](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/). This means, that it's necessary to provide a scheme (take a look [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml), to see all available schemes). So, in your case, you have to create the URI with string, like `file:/pic.png` or may be some other scheme.

As for your full path, it could be done like:

```
String string = "file:/C:/Users/Jurgen/newFile/myProject/pic.png";
```

Comment: Just one more question, why do you need to write "file:" in front of the path?

Comment: It determines the way you can handle this resource. In most cases, it refers to network protocols, data resources etc. Gern geschehen)